# What year did Henry Stauf first dream of the doll?

Tags: the-7th-guest

In the game The 7th Guest, Henry Stauf is described as "a drifter, moving from town to town robbing a gas station here, a grocery store there, until one night..." and I was wondering if there was any clue (or even direct reference) to when he grew to prominence as a toy maker.

If we consider the earliest possible chance for him to have robbed a "gas station" as 1888 (first [filling stations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filling_station#History) in America appeared in that year) and we assume the years mentioned in [this Wikia article](http://villains.wikia.com/wiki/Henry_Stauf), that the party being held 15 years after Stauf closed his house (which was purchased by the time he was famous), that the game takes place 50 years after the party, that The 11th Hour takes place 45 years after the events of the 7th Guest, and that the 11th Hour takes place at the same time that it was released in 1995 (which is challenged by the use of a portable PC with video which seems to place it closer to 2010) then the house would have been built in 1885 (3 years before there were gas stations to rob).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Stauf files contained in "The 11th Hour", Stauf murdered the woman returning from choir practice in June of 1929, and it was after that murder he first had his vision of the doll.

The Stauf files seem to outline a very short timeline though, Stauf announces the opening of his "Wonderworld Toys & Puzzles" in September of 1929 (you can get an authentic Stauf doll for $3.95) and the children start dying in the first half of October 1931. On October 17th 1931 he closes his business. His mansion is constructed sometime before that, because it's also in late October 1931 that he hosts the party, and Tad's mother reports him missing according to a police report dated November 3rd 1931.